# Why doesn't filter attached to the root logger propagate to descendant loggers?

Tags: python, logging

From paragraph 15.7.4 of the [python logging documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#filter-objects):

> Note that filters attached to handlers are consulted whenever an event
>   is emitted by the handler, whereas filters attached to loggers are
>   consulted whenever an event is logged to the handler (using debug(),
>   info(), etc.) This means that events which have been generated by
>   descendant loggers will not be filtered by a logger’s filter setting,
>   unless the filter has also been applied to those descendant loggers.

I don't understand this design decision. Would it not make more sense for the root logger's filter to be applied to the descendant loggers as well?

Comment: What would you do then if you wanted to override the filter?

Comment: It shouldn't be overridden. If you want a more restrictive filter in the descendant logger, you can always add one. It should not be possible to relax the restrictions of the parent logger's filter. Perhaps I should explain why I'm asking this - I'm trying to set up logging so that no matter what logger is created in the project, certain information is always filtered out. It would have been trivial if the filters propagated along the logger chain.

Comment: I don't agree, you should always be able to override behavior of a base class. If you never want something to be logged -- why is it being sent to the logger?

Comment: There are cases where certain information should not end up in the log, and there is no way to determine where it will crop up. It could be inside of a logged exception's stack trace, for example. Not logging any exceptions to prevent this would be silly.

Comment: You can be sure that if it worked the way you expected, someone would pipe up saying "why does it work like this? I want it to work the other way ..." :-) If you want to e.g. prevent stack traces being shown, that's something which is "audience" dependent, and it's best to prevent information getting out by placing filters on handlers for that audience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree: this is a counter-intuitive design decision, IMHO.

The easiest solution is to attach your filter to every possible handler.  For example, say you have a console handler, a mail handler and a database handler, you should attach your "root" filter to each and every one of them.  :-/

```
import logging
import logging.config

class MyRootFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        # filter out log messages that include "secret"
        if "secret" in record.msg:
            return False
        else:
            return True

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'my_root_filter': {
            '()': MyRootFilter,
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'stderr': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'filters': ['my_root_filter'],
        },
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'some.kind.of.EmailHandler',
            'filters': ['my_root_filter'],
        },
        'database': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'some.kind.of.DatabaseHandler',
            'filters': ['my_root_filter'],
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'some.sub.project': {
            'handlers': ['stderr'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
        },
    },
}

logging.config.dictConfig(LOGGING)
logging.getLogger("some.sub.project").error("hello")        # logs 'hello'
logging.getLogger("some.sub.project").error("hello secret") # filtered out!  :-)
```

If there are a lot of handlers, you may want to attach your root filter to every handler programmatically rather than manually.  I recommend you do this directly on your configuration dictionary (or file, depending on how you load your logging configuration), rather than doing this *after* the configuration has been loaded, because there seems to be no documented way to get the list of all handlers.  I found logger.handlers and logging._handlers, but since they are not documented, they may break in the future.  Plus, there's no guarantee that they are thread-safe.

The previous solution (attaching your root filter to every handler directly in the configuration, before it gets loaded) assumes that you have control over the logging configuration before it's loaded, and also that no handler will be added dynamically (using Logger#addHandler()).  If this is not true, then you may want to monkey-patch the logging module (good luck with that!).

**edit**

I took a shot at monkey patching Logger#addHandler, just for fun.  It actually works fine and simplifies the configuration, but I'm not sure I would recommend doing this (I hate monkey-patching, it makes it very hard to debug when something goes wrong).  Use at your own risks...

```
import logging
import logging.config

class MyRootFilter(logging.Filter):
   [...] # same as above

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'stderr': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            # it's shorter: there's no explicit reference to the root filter
        },
        [...]  # other handlers go here
    },
    'loggers': {
        'some.sub.project': {
            'handlers': ['stderr'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
        },
    },
}

def monkey_patched_addHandler(self, handler):
    result = self.old_addHandler(handler)
    self.addFilter(MyRootFilter())
    return result

logging.Logger.old_addHandler = logging.Logger.addHandler
logging.Logger.addHandler = monkey_patched_addHandler

logging.config.dictConfig(LOGGING)
logging.getLogger("some.sub.project").error("hello")        # logs 'hello'
logging.getLogger("some.sub.project").error("hello secret") # filtered out!  :-)
```

Comment: I've long passed the point of not caring about Python loggers, but your answer is on point. As much as I hate monkey-patching, it would be my preferred solution in this situation :)

Answer (score 4):

Filters, unlike levels and handlers, do not propagate. However, you can attach it to a handler which *will* propagate.

Check out this example by [Elliot at SaltyCrane Blog](https://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2014/02/python-logging-filters-do-not-propagate-like-handlers-and-levels-do/):

```
import logging

class MyFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        record.msg = 'MY FILTER: ' + record.msg
        return 1

myfilter = MyFilter()

myformatter = logging.Formatter("MY HANDLER: %(name)s - %(message)s")

myhandler = logging.StreamHandler()
myhandler.setFormatter(myformatter)
myhandler.addFilter(myfilter)

foo_logger = logging.getLogger('foo')
foo_logger.addHandler(myhandler)

foo_bar_logger = logging.getLogger('foo.bar')

foo_logger.error('asdfasdf')
foo_bar_logger.error('zxcvzxcv')
```

```
MY HANDLER: foo - MY FILTER: asdfasdf
MY HANDLER: foo.bar - MY FILTER: zxcvzxcv
```

Comment: I had a problem related to this: I wanted to set a format for all loggers, which included a new key, added on each log invocation by a filter. But setting that format and attaching that filter to the root logger resulted KeyError for each loggers, which had a different namespace. The above has helped to resolve the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Think about it this way.  Loggers are like the drain-pipes out of your home.  A filter on a logger prevents you from dumping stuff into the sewer, it doesn't filter the whole sewer.  Where you are in the flow (upstream, downstream) doesn't change this behavior.

Handlers are the pipes.  Pipes accumulate the upstream flow.  The default pipe is "skip, pass to parent".  If you want to affect the upstream flow, you need to put a filter no the pipe (handler).  If you look at the [logging flowchart](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#logging-flow), it should be possible to add a [NullHandler](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#nullhandler) (no formatting or output) that filters then propagates the message.

This is the behavior you desire.

Answer (score 0):

Analog to MiniQuark here is an imho elegant way for monkey patching (embeded in a context manager):

```py
from typing import Iterable, Iterator
from contextlib import contextmanager


@contextmanager
def apply_filter_for_new_handlers(filters: Iterable[logging.Filter]) -> Iterator[None]:
    originial_addHandler = logging.Logger.addHandler

    def monkey_patched_addHandler(self: logging.Logger, hdlr: logging.Handler) -> None: # noqa:C0103
        for log_filter in filters:
            hdlr.addFilter(log_filter)
        return originial_addHandler(self, hdlr)

    logging.Logger.addHandler = monkey_patched_addHandler
    yield

    logging.Logger.addHandler = originial_addHandler


class MyRootFilter(logging.Filter):
   [...] # same as above


with apply_filter_for_new_handlers(filters=[MyRootFilter]):
    logging.getLogger("some.sub.project").error("hello")
```